# Remove Fax information from the authorize.net merchant email receipt

Tags: email, authorize.net, receipt, fax

I'm using nsoftware and authorize.net as a gateway to handle payment in my web application. It is working fine. But, The users are getting a "merchant email receipt" with a "Fax:" info that I'd like to remove. I can't see a way to do it. Does anyone know how to do? Image attached.

[Merchant Email Receipt email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQRpq.png)

Comment: Sounds like a question for nsoftware's support? stackoverflow is for programming questions only. If you wrote code for this, please [edit] your question and add that code. See [ask].

Comment: This is not possible